# Employer recognition on projects you've done

Tags: software-industry

I've been trying to strengthen my resume as I have never been able to get an internship for computer science. So I decided to build a social network, not intended for public use but just for practice purposes. I've built a social network from SCRATCH, with the following specs,

login/logout/signup System, Friend System, Friend Request System, Messaging System, Ajax Live Chat between users, Newsfeed system (where users can post), Commenting system (where people can post on each post), Recent activities log system, Connections you might know system, page where people can upload their photos with image viewer slider and couple fews things here and there.

Would this project catch employers attention if everything was done from scratch? No code was copied or used from other people, for except only a few designing features.

Any suggestions or help would be appreciated, I cannot show the website yet because I haven't bought a public domain yet and I still need to work on a few things.

Comment: Until it survives contact with the real world and real users, preferably under heavy traffic, I'd be inclined to treat it as an interesting learning exercise but not an indication of competence. It's easy to write something that will pass a few tests, much harder to write something that will be robust, performant, scalable, secure, and so on.

Comment: You do realize that there are web-hosting companies that will host a web site for as little as $4.99 per year which includes a domain name? So there's no reason to not take your app to the next step. However, I would sell this as hobby programming and not an example of your work. Selling as a hobby indicates some initiative and demonstrates how much you enjoy programming. Selling as a "See What I Can Do" is dangerous because the odds are that what you can do isn't very good from a professional standpoint. Hobby = little blurb at the bottom of the resume. See What I Can Do = Section of its own

Comment: I would like to put it on my resume, so instead of mentioning "See What I Can Do", what other professional alternatives can I use? Do I state that programming is my hobby? @Dunk

Comment: @user:Yes, it should go on your resume. Just put it in the hobbies/interests section at the bottom. Just don't make it look like part of your credentials unless you truly believe it is of professional quality (which actually isn't that high of a bar for consumer software by today's standards).

Answer (score 2):

Your scheme will backfire in a bad way if your prospective employers evaluate your code as poorly architected, poorly written and inefficient. Any failure to include standard code that is widely known and tested in favor of writing code from scratch would be viewed none too kindly as reinventing the wheel.

To 'cover your back', you need to have your code reviewed by knowledgeable third parties. Your code is Exhibit A. Make sure that it's Exhibit A of something that's good about the way you code because the alternative is that it's Exhibit A of something that's not so good about the way you code.

Comment: Would poor architecture really be a mark against the OP? He appears to be seeking an entry level position.

Comment: @Dan If I have to scour your entire code base every time I have to make a specific change and I have to code in five scattered places to make that change, then your code is poorly architected and hiring you is not be worth my while. Whether it's fair of me to have my  expectation, I couldn't care less. I do have that expectation because I don't want to go  crazy and I operate by the Golden Rule: they who have the gold make the rules. Poorly architected code makes irrelevant that the code is well written - My life is still miserable.  Right or wrong, this is my point of view.